# How can I vertically-align child elements of a div while keeping them floated to the left and right?

Tags: html, css

I am re-writing parts of an existing website and would very much like to clean up some things. Currently, where certain child elements in a parent div are `float`ed (left and right), I have to use `margin-top: 7px;` to push the left-floated child element down a bit so it's inline with the right-floated child element.

I don't like doing this.

Below is what I expect to see:

[image: Expected Result]

But that's not what I see. Instead, I see this:

[image: Current Result]

So I tried a few things to see if I could fix it. The original code is:

```
<div id="bottomHeader">
    <p>Some slogan here</p>
    <ul id="SocialLinks">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="~/!/Assets/Images/Twitter.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="~/!/Assets/Images/Facebook.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#bottomHeader { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; }
#bottomHeader > p { text-align: left; }
#bottomHeader > p { text-align: right; }
```

Which aligns them left and right, but the `p` element is higher than the `ul` element. I realised that this is because both elements have a default width of 100%. So the `p` element is pushing the `ul` element down beneath it.

So then I just thought that if I make both elements have a max-width of 50%, it'll be alright. But, nope. When I do that, the ul element (which is supposed to be right-aligned), is appearing in the center somewhere (almost as if it's left-aligned). So then I changed the code to:

```
#bottomHeader { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; }
#bottomHeader > p { width: 50%; float: left; }
#bottomHeader > p { width: 50%; float: right; }
```

Which worked. *However*, now the parent div (see dark blue rectangle in pic above) has a height less than the height of its child elements, like so:

[image: Almost got it]

But that's still not quite right. 'Cause now it looks like the child elements of the div are outside and below their parent div. And it also breaks the layout a little.

---

How can I vertically-align child elements of a div while keeping them floated to the left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `display: inline-block` is what you are looking for.

It makes the element act as both block-level box, and an inline-level box.

Like this:

```
#bottomHeader { 
    width: 80%; 
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%; 
    background:pink; 
    display:inline-block;
    height: auto; 
}
```

**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zHpr3/4/)**

Comment: Ah crud. I always forget about inline-block. Thank you @Froient.